# Code copied exactly to second page is not working

Tags: javascript, php, css

I was told to copy some existing functionality to another page (a rating system with stars that appear and you can mouseover them to raise or lower the rating; the stars appear filled in according to the rating and the rest are just outlines), but the stars on not appearing on the second page.

I made sure that I copied the call to the CSS and the JavaScript file correctly. When I hard code the stars to appear, they do appear but the mouseover just highlights the star the mouse is over and not all the stars from the first star until the one the mouse is over. The original page does not hard code the stars, so I don't know why it works in one page but not the other.

From the original page, the CSS is called at the top of the page:

```
@import "<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/rating.min.css";
```

The code is inserted into the page here:

```
echo '<div style="height: 24px; padding: 5px;"><label>Transcript Quality:</label><span id="qualitystars" style="vertical-align: sub;"></span></div>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="quality" id="quality"' . (isset($transcriber['quality']) ? ' value="' . $transcriber['quality'] . '"' : '') . '>';
```

The JavaScript is called here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/rating.min.js"></script>
```

In the new page, I call the CSS:

```
@import "<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/rating.min.css";
```

I then insert the code into the page:

```
echo 'Please rate the quality of this transcript:<br/>';
echo '<div style="height: 44px; padding: 5px;">';
echo '<span id="qualitystars" style="vertical-align: sub;"></span>';
echo '</div>
```

I copied these elements into the new page, but nothing shows up in the second page (`id="qualitystars"`). The only thing I could think is that this is being called inside a TINY.box, but why would that make a difference?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. check if your url is relevant to the new page 2.look at F12 and see if you get same errors

Comment: @לבנימלכה, would that be the URL for the css? I will try that and get back to you. Toda.

Comment: The URL is correct. When I press F12, I get an error, but the console is blank so I can't see what the error is.

Comment: I got the error message to appear and will go from there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry! I totally misread that line of code. It's CSS, not PHP. Please ignore my comment (I've removed it anyway to avoid misleading others).